# The Laravel named route method doesn't generate host server's (apache) alias when generating the URL on view

Tags: laravel, apache, laravel-routing

I wanted to send an email with a button with link to the page I wanted to redirect the recipient to. I have this named route on my `web.php` route file:

```
Route::get('/', [ProbationPeriodController::class, 'index'])->name('Probation.index');
```

and I added this code for the button on my email view:

```
<a href="{{route('Probation.index')}}" target="_blank">Take Action</a>
```

I have hosted my application on apache server on windows with an alias shortcut of `apps` and the configuration works fine.
I have also configured the `.htaccess` file to reflect the alias and it works fine throughout the whole application. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /apps/

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Add /apps/ After The IP Address or Domain name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/apps
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /apps/$1 [L]
```

The problem arises when I use the named route **Probation.index** on the **email view**. The email sends fine but when the recipient clicks on the button, it gives them a URL without the alias name.
I expect this: `http://example.com/apps/probation` but the result omits the `apps` and shows `http://example.com/probation`. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: try `route('Probation.index','apps')`

Comment: You need to add env var APP_URL - router determine host from this.

Answer (score 0):

@Maksim Thank you. It solved the problem. I wish you had written an answer rather than a comment so that I could approve it as an accepted answer and upvote you.
I modified my `.env` file and updated the `APP_URL` to the appropriate prefix of my routes.